# Missing menu in Tkinter GUI

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I have developed a script for image analysis and would like to wrap it with a GUI. I have decided to use tkinter. I have created a class which when I try to initilise is missing a menu that I have scripted for. I am slightly confused as to why my script is not working, I am new to tkinter and also to classes, which adds to the confusion :) Any help as to why my script is not working would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

```
import tkinter as tk

#from tkinter import filedialog

class Window(Frame):

 def __init__(self, master=None):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)               
    self.master = master
    self.init_window()
 def init_window(self):
    self.master.title("Lifespan Data Analyser")
    self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)


    menu = Menu(self.master)
    self.master.config(menu=menu)        
    file = Menu(menu)
    file.add_command(label='Exit', command = self.frame.quit)        
    menu.add_cascade(label ='File', menu=file)

    browse = Menu(menu)
    browse.add_command(label='Browse', command=self.browse_button)
    menu.add_cascade(label='Start',menu=browse)


 def browse_button(self):
    global file_path
    # Allow user to select a directory and store it in global var
    file_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    file_path=str(file_path)

    print(file_path)


root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")
app = Window(root) 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When you say “buttons”, do you mean the menu items? I don’t see where you are creating any `Button` widgets.

Comment: Apologies, Yes I mean the menu items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try to add the "Exit" item to the File menu I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'frame'
```

which makes sense as there is no attribute "frame". I'm thinking this maybe works better:

```
file.add_command(label='Exit', command=self.master.destroy)
```